# How to extract int from QBytearray?

Tags: arrays, qt, bit-manipulation

I'm a newbie in Qt. I'm doing UART communication with Arduino. On the Qt side, I'm reading few bytes in and storing them in QBytearray which looks like **"3b4800000a0d"** and values are in hex. Now I want to know how to extract integer values from this?
So, my integers are not always of length 8, 16. Some of them are 4bit in length and some of them are 15 bits in length. So basically, I want to perform a bitwise operation in this, which is not possible in QByteArray, which when done shows some error.

Can some please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you just use `QByteArray::toLongLong()` and do your bitwise operations on that?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I have done that. However, the received array is of 40 Bytes, and hence the conversion is failing. Possibly becoz "toLongLong" cannot do this size of conversion.  what should I do now?

Comment: Well, you need to provide more information. Don't just vaguely say that you receive 40 bytes. Give an actual example of something you want to parse, and give the actual code you're using to parse it, and give the actual error you get when you try it.